How to Filter Follow-Up Data Within ±120 Days of 1 Year from Baseline in R
I am new to R. I am working with a dataset in R where each patient is identified by a unique subjectid. Each patient has a baseline_date and multiple follow-up dates (fu_date). I want to filter follow-up records for each subjectid that fall within ±120 days of exactly 1 year (365 days) from the baseline_date.
After filtering, I need to calculate the total exacerbations (fu_exacerbations) for each patient during this period, making this a new column. How can I implement this in R?
This is the test_data.
Thanks a lot for your time!
I dont know how to go about it.

Welcome to SO. Please take the tour and read this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?   Then edit your question accordingly.

Thank you. I will give it a read. Thanks for sharing!

First of let's look at your data:

The 31.6.2022 must be a mistake because June only has 30 days. It should be the 30.6.2022, right? I don't know where this data is coming from, but it should be carefully checked if it's health-related! We can do a basic sanity check on the dates of this column.
We should fill in the missing baseline_dates using the fill function. Only then we can calculate the days from baseline like this days_from_baseline = as.numeric(difftime(fu_date, baseline_date, units = "days"))) and filter the abs-days-number for <= 120 days. Afterward, we summarize fu_exacerbations and finally right join it with the underlying data frame:
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

# read data from csv
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path))
# read csv in file folder
df <-  read.csv("test_data.csv")

# To correct dates like "31.6.22" to "30.6.22":
clean_date <- function(date) {
  # Ensure the date is character to avoid errors
  date <- as.character(date)
  # Extract components of the date
  month <- as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(date, "^\\d{1,2}"))
  day <- as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(date, "(?<=/)\\d{1,2}(?=/)"))
  year <- as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(date, "\\d{4}"))
  # Correct invalid days based on the month
  day <- dplyr::case_when(
    month == 4 & day > 30 ~ 30,  # April
    month == 6 & day > 30 ~ 30,  # June
    month == 9 & day > 30 ~ 30,  # September
    month == 11 & day > 30 ~ 30, # November
    month == 2 & day > 28 ~ 28,  # February (not handling leap years)
    TRUE ~ day
  )
  return(sprintf("%02d/%02d/%04d", month, day, year))
}


# use the function and then fill
result <- df %>% mutate(
  baseline_date = if_else(baseline_date != "", clean_date(baseline_date), NA),
  # sanity check dates with clean_date
  fu_date = if_else(fu_date != "", clean_date(fu_date), NA)
) %>%
  fill(baseline_date) %>%
  # Group by patient
  group_by(subjectid) %>%
  # Calculate days from baseline for each follow-up date
  mutate(days_from_baseline = as.numeric(difftime(
    as.Date(fu_date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
    as.Date(baseline_date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
    units = "days"
  ))) %>%
  # Filter records within ±120 days of 1 year
  filter(abs(days_from_baseline - 365) <= 120) %>%
  # Sum exacerbations for each patient
  summarize(total_exacerbations = sum(fu_exacerbations, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  # Join back with original data to keep other baseline information if needed
  right_join(df %>% select(subjectid, baseline_date) %>% distinct(subjectid),
             by = "subjectid")

print(result)

It will look like this:
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  subjectid total_exacerbations baseline_date
      <int>               <int> <date>       
1         2                   4 2022-06-30   
2         1                  NA 2022-11-14   


This worked flawlessly!!!! Thank you so much. I was really struggling with it. And the way you explained made so much sense!
(You are right about the date)
